# font-awesome circles not showing up

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

in my package.json, I have

```
 "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
  }
```

in my html, I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
```

If I comment out the second link, none of my font-awesome icons show up and I only get empty rectangles.

in my css, I have

```
fas fa-circle
```

Anyone seeing what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think your are mismatching the versions of 5.6.3 with 4.7.0

Comment: Why are you linking to 2 font awesome files?
What's in the first link? Is that file actually there in that folder?

Comment: And yes, the "fas" class is new to version 5. So if the first link is version 4, that's why it's not working with that file.

Comment: as I said in the original message: If I comment out the second link, none of my font-awesome icons show up and I only get empty rectangles.

Comment: remove font awesome from dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for version 4.7.0 installed locally, I should use fa instead of fas.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

and the package is

```
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is for version 5 and above

In your HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then, Use this code

```
<span><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span> // for Solid
<span><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span> // for Regular
```

And, This is for version 4.7.0

In your HTML,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then,

```
<span><i class="fa fa-circle-thin" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<span><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<span><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Comment: as I said in the original post , If I comment out the second link, none of my font-awesome icons show up and I only get empty rectangles. what I am trying to find it is why am I not seeing the rectangle with the one read from node_modules

Comment: @reza I have already faced this. It was a version mismatch problem. You should use the correct cdn link, and you should use the icon in same version of that cdn link. Otherwise it displays the rectangle. And the second scenario is you css. If you apply your own css for the icon directly, then the icon will affect with your css. Please, Make sure you didn't change any default styles of the icon